# Prevent MediaPlayer from play all mp3 files in the folder automatically

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm from Taiwan and my English is pretty basic, thanks for your forgiveness.

I built a iPad app and published to App Store, which is a kind of communicating board (AAC for the person who has difficult on speaking). It has several buttons on main view and when user touch up one, the app will play a mp3 sound corresponding to that button. I've put all mp3 files on a folder and determining which one to play dynamically at run-time.

Recently I'm working on build the Android version of this app, but I meet a problem that is when I touch up one button on the view, the MediaPlayer play not only the corresponding one but keep playing all the rest mp3 files on the folder continuously. It doesn't happen on the development of iPad version. Any one can help me to resolve this problem and set the MediaPlayer up to working appropriately?

PS. I put all MP3 files on some sub-folders and put them on the "assets" folder. It because for some reasons, all mp3 files are using numeric file name (ex. 0123223.mp3), and which MP3 to play is according to which button user touched up, so I can't use R.raw.0123223 not only because  the R class can't has a member named in numeric, but also the target mp3 file can only determining at run-time instead of compile-time, so I can't use the res/raw folder.

My code is as following:

```
private void PlayMP3(String mp3File) throws IOException {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getAssets().openFd(mp3File);
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        System.out.println(mp.getAudioSessionId() + " finished.");
        }           
    });
    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
    player.setLooping(false);
    player.prepare();
    player.start();
}
```

the parameter "mp3file" of PlayMP3 is a concatenated string of mp3 file path, according to the button user touched up.

Many thanks!

Comment: How are you playing the files? Post some code here and we can move on from there.

Comment: Sorry that I omitted my code. I've re-edit my post to add my code and the reason why I've not use the res/raw folder to locating the mp3 files. Thank for your replies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your version would work if you had only that one file in the assets directory. The asset directory contents are put together one after another. So, if you do not specify where to start and how many bytes to read, the player will read up to the end as if they are one file.

You can accomplish what you want by using setDataSource with more arguments:

```
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
```

This will allow you to define the limits of the player and only play the song you specify in your string mp3File.

Answer (score 0):

You did not post some code.

First step is to insert your sound file into the raw folder

Then, you need only a few lines of code:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.mysoundfile);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

When the application is closing, dont forget to "release" your media player:

```
mediaPlayer.release();
mediaPlayer = null;
```

Comment: Sorry that I omitted my code. I've re-edit my post to add my code and the reason why I've not use the res/raw folder to locating the mp3 files. Thank for your replies!